# Generating a table of glyphs with XeTeX

Tags: fonts, tables, symbols, xetex, automation

I am trying to get XeTeX to generate a table of all the possible glyphs of a given font, but can not figure out how to make XeTeX know how many glyphs the font has, so I have to specify an exact number.

This is what I have got so far:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm,10pt,landscape]{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xunicode, xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Historical}, Alternate=0]{Linux Libertine O}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{10}
\newcount\charcount
\charcount=0
\loop
\number\charcount \hspace{1ex} \XeTeXglyph\charcount
\par
\ifnum\charcount<2500
\advance\charcount1
\repeat
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example.]

**Fig. 1:** Example of the output.

How can it automatically know the exact number of accessible glyphs?

**Bonus:** Is anyone willing to waste his time by making it put everything inside a table with 10 columns? :-) It also reports an error probably caused by `multicol` which a I could not fix yet.

Comment: This might be easier to do with LuaTeX.

Comment: @Caramdir: It won't be more difficult to do with XeTeX.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. Use `\iffontchar\font` number  ... `\fi` to test if a glyph is in the font.
2. `multicol` is OK for me. Set `\parindent` to 0pt to get proper result.

Here is a neat example:

[image: First page]
...
[image: 7th page]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{multido}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{"10000}{% from U+0000 to U+FFFF
  \iffontchar\font\i
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \symbol{\i}\endgraf
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note: I tried my best to keep the code simple. But there're still two unusual points: I use `\iffontchar` to test the font characters, and use `\endgraf` instead of `\par` to cheat `\multido`.

Comment: It works very well, but I had to reduce the number to 9999. Egreg mentioned that the last glyph of Linux Libertine O produces an error and this was probably the same case. Thank you! **All three answers are very useful to me, but I am going to accept this one as it uses XeTeX and `multicol`.**

Comment: In case you want to print symbols from a font without normal letters and numbers, don't forget to set some _other_ (normal) font as the main font so that you see the keys in the table.

Answer (score 18):

I know that you are asking for a solution with XeTeX (and egreg already gave one), but here is a LuaTeX solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\newfontface\thefont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\section*{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{multicols}{7}\noindent
\begin{luacode*}
local f = fontloader.open('/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/fxlr.otf')

local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end

table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)

for i = 1, #glyphs do
   tex.sprint(glyphs[i].unicode .. ': ')
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
       tex.sprint('{\\thefont\\char' .. glyphs[i].unicode .. '}');
   end
   tex.sprint(' {\\tiny (')
   tex.sprint(-2, glyphs[i].name)
   tex.sprint(')}\\\\')
end

fontloader.close(f)
\end{luacode*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: part of the result]

Comment: You can simplify your loops, instead of `i=1 while i<foo do i = i+1 end` use `for i=1, foo do end`

Comment: You also don't need to re-load the font in lua, you can access the table of the current font using `fonts.identifiers[font.current()]`.

Comment: @Khaled: True. I based that on some code in the LuaTeX manual, which had those loops. I'll change the code. That second comment looks useful. However, since the main font is LM (so that one can also list, e.g., dingbat fonts), this won't work.

Comment: Thank you, it is a motivation to learn Lua. I do not understand some parts of it yet.

Comment: You can do something like `\font\foo={name:Linux Libertine O}` and in lua `f = fonts.identifiers[font.id("foo")]` so you don't need to locate the font manually.

Comment: @Khaled: Is this documented somewhere in the LuaTeX manual?

Comment: `font.id()` is documented in the manual, `fonts.identifiers` is a luaotfload (and ConTeXt) specific structure.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,textwidth=239mm,textheight=480pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcount\charcount
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\chardef\highest=\XeTeXcountglyphs\font
\offinterlineskip
\loop
\makebox[15mm][l]{\strut\vrule\,\number\charcount\hfill \XeTeXglyph\charcount}\hskip1mm plus 1mm
\ifnum\charcount<\numexpr\highest-1\relax
\advance\charcount1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

With Linux Libertine the last glyph produces an error, that's the reason of the strange limitation. This does not happen with other fonts.

If one wants a table with the actual codes for the characters, a slower routine must be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,textwidth=239mm,textheight=480pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\newcount\charcount
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\offinterlineskip
\def\dochar{\iffontchar\font\charcount
  \makebox[15mm][l]{\strut\vrule\,{\tiny\number\charcount}\hfill\char\charcount}\hskip1mm plus 1mm
  \fi}
\loop\dochar
\ifnum\charcount<"10FFFF\relax
\advance\charcount1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: The range is wrong. `\XeTeXcountglyphs\font` returns the number of glyphs in current font, but not the highest glyph code in current font. In Linux Libertine, there are 2575 (`\XeTeXcountglyphs\font`) glyphs, but U+FFFD (`\symbol{65533}`) is the last symbol.

Comment: @LeoLiu, if you use `\XeTeXcountglyphs\font` together with `\XeTeXglyph` it works perfectly fine and prints all glyphs.
based on your previously posted code:
`\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{\XeTeXcountglyphs\font}{% from U+0000 to U+FFFF
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \XeTeXglyph\i\endgraf
}`

Answer (score 4):

## Supplemental Answer

I was looking at some of the answers, and I decided to write a similar one using PGF/TikZ. So, for the sake of the community, here it is!

The fast-to-typeset version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxstep{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235688/13552
\typeout{maxstep is \maxstep} % Prints maxstep to log
Number of glyphs: \maxstep\\
\begin{multicols}{5}
\foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
    %\iffontchar\font\charstep
        \makebox[3em][l]{\small\charstep}%
        \XeTeXglyph\charstep
        \endgraf
    %\else
        %\charstep{} not exist
    %\fi
}%
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The slow-to-typeset, `\tikzpicture` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\maxstep{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235688/13552
\typeout{maxstep is \maxstep} % Prints maxstep to log
\foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
    %\iffontchar\font\charstep
        \makebox[3em][l]{\small\charstep}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
            \node [red,font=\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont] {\XeTeXglyph\charstep};
        \end{tikzpicture}\endgraf
    %\else
        %\charstep{} not exist
    %\fi
}%
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The great thing about using `\XeTeXglyph` as Paul suggested is that you do not need to check  whether or not the characters exist. This is why I commented out the if statement (`\iffontchar\font\charstep`).

Note that instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`, you could use `\edef`:

```
\edef\maxstep{\the\numexpr\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1\relax} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235686/13552
```

It also works with Leo Liu's answer as mentioned by Paul. Here is an example:

```
\begin{multicols}{5}
\multido{\i=0+1}{\XeTeXcountglyphs\font}{
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \XeTeXglyph\i\endgraf
}%
\end{multicols}
```

## Related Questions

- [Generating a table of all glyphs – including meta data like name, Unicode etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160091/generating-a-table-of-all-glyphs-including-meta-data-like-name-unicode-etc)
- [How can I use \XeTeXcountglyphs\font in a pgf \foreach macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235685/how-can-i-use-xetexcountglyphs-font-in-a-pgf-foreach-macro)