# Generating a table of all glyphs – including meta data like name, Unicode etc

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, opentype

The answers to [Generating a table of glyphs with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/generating-a-table-of-glyphs-with-xetex) cycle through character positions in the font and output a glyph (and its ordinal number) if one is assigned to that position, which is only sometimes the same as Unicode position. Some glyphs may be shared by several Unicode code points. Some Unicode code points have several glyphs assigned to them, possibly selected by smart font features. Furthermore, Unicode has more positions than fit into 16bit (as in Open Type).

I can use a font editor to look up the names assigned to glyphs, which may adhere to Adobe’s glyph naming standards, but often deviate from that, especially for alternate glyphs (dot suffixes) and for non-roman characters. Nevertheless, I want to print out a customizable glyph list containing that info using XeLaTeX.

How can I adapt @LeoLiu’s code, repeated below, to show glyph names besides ordinal number?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{"10000}{% from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF
  \iffontchar\font\i
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \symbol{\i}\endgraf
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

JFTR, as it happens the [`libertine` package documentation](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf) and [guide](http://linuxlibertine.sourceforge.net/latex/libertinedokuxelatex.pdf) already include glyph lists, but they might be out of date and I want to do it for other fonts, too. The former has some code that might be relevant, because it seems to generate glyph lists, but I don’t understand it (i.e. the `cathode` magic, I guess):

```
\renewcommand\DeclareTextGlyphY[3]{%
  \makebox[2.5cm]{\LARGE\strut\fbox{\biolinumKeyGlyph{#2}}} #2\\}%
\catcode`\_=12%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\noindent
\input{LinBiolinum_K}
\end{multicols}
```

Update: This is the code from `libertine.sty` (for XeTeX and LuaTeX) which is adapted by the code above:

```
\providecommand*\DeclareTextGlyphY[3]{%
  % \DeclareTextGlyphY{fxl}{s_t}{64262}
  % #1=basefont #2=glyphname, #3=position
  \def\lib@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxl \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\libertine\char#3\relax}}\else%
    \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxb \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\biolinum\char#3\relax}}\else%
      \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxk \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\biolinumkey\char#3\relax}}\else%
        \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxi \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\libertineInitial\char#3\relax}}\else%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi}
%
\input{LinLibertine_R}
\input{LinBiolinum_R}
\input{LinBiolinum_K}
\input{LinLibertine_I}
%
\DeclareRobustCommand*\libertineGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinLibertine_R@#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\biolinumGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinBiolinum_R@#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\biolinumKeyGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinBiolinum_K@#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\libertineInitialGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinLibertine_I@#1}}
```

The files `LinLibertine_R.tex`, `LinBiolinum_R.tex`, `LinBiolinum_K.tex` and `LinLibertine_I.tex` contain a lot of `\DeclareTextGlyphY` calls and nothing else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With XeTeX you can get glyph by name, but I don't think it's possible to map the name to the Unicode point, which wouldn't make sense anyway, because a code point can correspond to several glyphs.

Here's how: if you know the name, say `zero.slash`, you can print the glyph with

```
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"zero.slash"<space>
```

I got the list of glyph names for Linux Libertine O with

```
otfinfo -g `kpsewhich LinLibertine_R.otf` > libert.list
```

which produced the text file

```
.notdef
space
exclam
quotedbl
numbersign
dollar
percent
ampersand
quotesingle
parenleft
parenright
asterisk
...
longs_t
s_t
uniFFFD
u1D538
u1D539
u1D53B
u1D53C
u1D53D
u1D53E
u1D540
u1D541
u1D542
u1D543
u1D544
u1D546
u1D547
u1D54A
u1D54B
u1D54C
u1D54D
u1D54E
u1D54F
u1D550
```

and then ran the following LaTeX document with XeLaTeX: it just loops over the file and feeds lines to the mapping function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,fontspec,multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \crissov_print_list:n { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_crissov_input_stream
\cs_new_protected:Npn \crissov_print_list:n #1
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_crissov_input_stream { #1 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_crissov_input_stream
   {
    \makebox[2.5em][l]{\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"##1"~}
    {\footnotesize(##1)}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\printlist{libert.list}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This is a picture of the last page:

[image]

Note that the last glyph never shows up due to what I think is a bug in XeTeX.

Comment: Ah, I thought XeTeX could also somehow do the `otfinfo` part.

Comment: @Crissov Probably it accesses the table when executing `\XeTeXglyphindex`, without loading it entirely.

Comment: PS: I needed to install `lcdftypetools` from CTAN to get `otfinfo` first.

Comment: @Crissov I always have a full TeX Live.

Comment: Sure, most people have, but some are on ultrabooks with limited SSD space.

Answer (score 3):

*Amended answer*

This version does Unicode blocks as well as a glyphlist:

[image: Unicode blocks]

[image: Glyph List]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\pagecolor{brown!3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newtoggle{printastring}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\newfontfamily\flab{Noto Serif}% for labels

\let\nc\newcommand

\nc\mypathname{C:/Windows/Fonts/}
\nc\myext{.ttf}
\nc\myfilename{xxx}
\nc\myfont{\mypathname\myfilename\myext}


\nc\fstartrange{97}
\nc\fendrange{122}

\begin{luacode}
    function printmysample(mystart, myfinish)
--  tex.sprint(myfont)
--local f = fontloader.open(myfont)
local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)
--   tex.sprint('Sample\\\\')
--tex.sprint(f.glyphmax .. ' glyphs\\\\')
for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode >= mystart ) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode <= myfinish ) then
                tex.sprint("\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
           end
           end
   end
end
--fontloader.close(f)

    end
\end{luacode}

\nc\doprintmysample[2]{%
\begin{quotation}
\noindent\directlua{printmysample(#1 ,#2)}
\end{quotation}
\par\bigskip
}






\begin{luacode}
    function openmyfont(xxx)
      f = fontloader.open(xxx)
      tex.sprint("{\\flab\\section{" .. f.fullname .. "}}")
      tex.sprint("{\\flab " .. f.fullname .. ", " .. f.glyphcnt .. " chars}\\par\\bigskip")
 end
\end{luacode}


\begin{luacode}
    function closemyfont(xxx)
        fontloader.close(f)
  end
\end{luacode}

%=================

%=================
\begin{luacode}
    function printglyphliste()
    tex.sprint("\\subsection{Glyph List}")
    tex.sprint("\\begin{multicols}{6}")
local glyphs = {}
local ck = 0
local pc = 0
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)

for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
--              tex.sprint("\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
                    tex.sprint("{\\centering\\noindent\\begin{tabular}{c}\\huge{\\color{blue}\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}\\\\ { \\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny\\detokenize{" .. glyphs[i].name .. "}}\\\\ { \\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny\\colorbox{blue!8}{" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}}\\\\\\hline\\end{tabular} \\par}")
   end
end
    tex.sprint("{\\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny [End of List]}\\par")
    tex.sprint("\\end{multicols}")
end
\end{luacode}

%=================
\begin{luacode}
    function printmyblocke(blockstart,blockfinish,blockname)
local glyphs = {}
local ck = 0
local pc = 0
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)
for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode >= blockstart ) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode <= blockfinish ) then
      if (blockname == 'Combining Diacritical Marks') 
          or (blockname == 'Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement') 
            then -- a holder for the mark
                tex.sprint("o\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
                else
                tex.sprint("\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
                end
          ck = ck + 1
           end
           end
   end
end
--  pc = ck / (blockfinish-blockstart+1) * 100
--  tex.sprint(f.fullname .. "\\par")
    if ck > 0 then
        tex.sprint("\\par {\\flab - " .. blockname .. "}\\par\\par  \\bigskip")
--      tex.sprint(ck .. " out of [" .. blockfinish-blockstart+1 .. "] chars:  " .. pc .. "\\par")
        end
--  fontloader.close(f)
    end
\end{luacode}



\nc\doprmb[3]{%
{\directlua{printmyblocke(#1,#2,#3)}}
}



\nc\wiafprintchars[1]{%
\doopenmyfont{#1}
\doprintmysample{\fstartrange}{\fendrange}
\subsection{Unicode Blocks}
\doprmb{125184}{125279}{'Adlam'}
\doprmb{65792}{65855}{'Aegean Numbers'}
\doprmb{71424}{71487}{'Ahom'}
\doprmb{128768}{128895}{'Alchemical Symbols'}
\doprmb{64256}{64335}{'Alphabetic Presentation Forms'}
\doprmb{82944}{83583}{'Anatolian Hieroglyphs'}
\doprmb{119296}{119375}{'Ancient Greek Musical Notation'}
\doprmb{65856}{65935}{'Ancient Greek Numbers'}
\doprmb{65936}{65999}{'Ancient Symbols'}
\doprmb{1536}{1791}{'Arabic'}
\doprmb{2208}{2303}{'Arabic Extended-A'}
\doprmb{126464}{126719}{'Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols'}
\doprmb{64336}{65023}{'Arabic Presentation Forms-A'}
\doprmb{65136}{65279}{'Arabic Presentation Forms-B'}
\doprmb{1872}{1919}{'Arabic Supplement'}
\doprmb{1328}{1423}{'Armenian'}
\doprmb{8592}{8703}{'Arrows'}
\doprmb{68352}{68415}{'Avestan'}
\doprmb{6912}{7039}{'Balinese'}
\doprmb{42656}{42751}{'Bamum'}
\doprmb{92160}{92735}{'Bamum Supplement'}
\doprmb{0}{127}{'Basic Latin'}
\doprmb{92880}{92927}{'Bassa Vah'}
\doprmb{7104}{7167}{'Batak'}
\doprmb{2432}{2559}{'Bengali'}
\doprmb{72704}{72815}{'Bhaiksuki'}
\doprmb{9600}{9631}{'Block Elements'}
\doprmb{12544}{12591}{'Bopomofo'}
\doprmb{12704}{12735}{'Bopomofo Extended'}
\doprmb{9472}{9599}{'Box Drawing'}
\doprmb{69632}{69759}{'Brahmi'}
\doprmb{10240}{10495}{'Braille Patterns'}
\doprmb{6656}{6687}{'Buginese'}
\doprmb{5952}{5983}{'Buhid'}
\doprmb{118784}{119039}{'Byzantine Musical Symbols'}
\doprmb{66208}{66271}{'Carian'}
\doprmb{66864}{66927}{'Caucasian Albanian'}
\doprmb{69888}{69967}{'Chakma'}
\doprmb{43520}{43615}{'Cham'}
\doprmb{5024}{5119}{'Cherokee'}
\doprmb{43888}{43967}{'Cherokee Supplement'}
\doprmb{129536}{129647}{'Chess Symbols'}
\doprmb{69552}{69599}{'Chorasmian'}
\doprmb{13056}{13311}{'CJK Compatibility'}
\doprmb{65072}{65103}{'CJK Compatibility Forms'}
\doprmb{63744}{64255}{'CJK Compatibility Ideographs'}
\doprmb{194560}{195103}{'CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement'}
\doprmb{11904}{12031}{'CJK Radicals Supplement'}
\doprmb{12736}{12783}{'CJK Strokes'}
\doprmb{12288}{12351}{'CJK Symbols and Punctuation'}
\doprmb{19968}{40959}{'CJK Unified Ideographs'}
\doprmb{13312}{19903}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A'}
\doprmb{131072}{173791}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B'}
\doprmb{173824}{177983}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C'}
\doprmb{177984}{178207}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D'}
\doprmb{178208}{183983}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E'}
\doprmb{183984}{191471}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F'}
\doprmb{196608}{201551}{'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G'}
\doprmb{768}{879}{'Combining Diacritical Marks'}
\doprmb{6832}{6911}{'Combining Diacritical Marks Extended'}
\doprmb{8400}{8447}{'Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols'}
\doprmb{7616}{7679}{'Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement'}
\doprmb{65056}{65071}{'Combining Half Marks'}
\doprmb{43056}{43071}{'Common Indic Number Forms'}
\doprmb{9216}{9279}{'Control Pictures'}
\doprmb{11392}{11519}{'Coptic'}
\doprmb{66272}{66303}{'Coptic Epact Numbers'}
\doprmb{119648}{119679}{'Counting Rod Numerals'}
\doprmb{73728}{74751}{'Cuneiform'}
\doprmb{74752}{74879}{'Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation'}
\doprmb{8352}{8399}{'Currency Symbols'}
\doprmb{67584}{67647}{'Cypriot Syllabary'}
\doprmb{1024}{1279}{'Cyrillic'}
\doprmb{11744}{11775}{'Cyrillic Extended-A'}
\doprmb{42560}{42655}{'Cyrillic Extended-B'}
\doprmb{7296}{7311}{'Cyrillic Extended-C'}
\doprmb{1280}{1327}{'Cyrillic Supplement'}
\doprmb{66560}{66639}{'Deseret'}
\doprmb{2304}{2431}{'Devanagari'}
\doprmb{43232}{43263}{'Devanagari Extended'}
\doprmb{9984}{10175}{'Dingbats'}
\doprmb{71936}{72031}{'Dives Akuru'}
\doprmb{71680}{71759}{'Dogra'}
\doprmb{127024}{127135}{'Domino Tiles'}
\doprmb{113664}{113823}{'Duployan'}
\doprmb{74880}{75087}{'Early Dynastic Cuneiform'}
\doprmb{78896}{78911}{'Egyptian Hieroglyph Format Controls'}
\doprmb{77824}{78895}{'Egyptian Hieroglyphs'}
\doprmb{66816}{66863}{'Elbasan'}
\doprmb{69600}{69631}{'Elymaic'}
\doprmb{128512}{128591}{'Emoticons'}
\doprmb{127232}{127487}{'Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement'}
\doprmb{9312}{9471}{'Enclosed Alphanumerics'}
\doprmb{12800}{13055}{'Enclosed CJK Letters and Months'}
\doprmb{127488}{127743}{'Enclosed Ideographic Supplement'}
\doprmb{4608}{4991}{'Ethiopic'}
\doprmb{11648}{11743}{'Ethiopic Extended'}
\doprmb{43776}{43823}{'Ethiopic Extended-A'}
\doprmb{4992}{5023}{'Ethiopic Supplement'}
\doprmb{8192}{8303}{'General Punctuation'}
\doprmb{9632}{9727}{'Geometric Shapes'}
\doprmb{128896}{129023}{'Geometric Shapes Extended'}
\doprmb{4256}{4351}{'Georgian'}
\doprmb{7312}{7359}{'Georgian Extended'}
\doprmb{11520}{11567}{'Georgian Supplement'}
\doprmb{11264}{11359}{'Glagolitic'}
\doprmb{122880}{122927}{'Glagolitic Supplement'}
\doprmb{66352}{66383}{'Gothic'}
\doprmb{70400}{70527}{'Grantha'}
\doprmb{880}{1023}{'Greek and Coptic'}
\doprmb{7936}{8191}{'Greek Extended'}
\doprmb{2688}{2815}{'Gujarati'}
\doprmb{73056}{73135}{'Gunjala Gondi'}
\doprmb{2560}{2687}{'Gurmukhi'}
\doprmb{65280}{65519}{'Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms'}
\doprmb{12592}{12687}{'Hangul Compatibility Jamo'}
\doprmb{4352}{4607}{'Hangul Jamo'}
\doprmb{43360}{43391}{'Hangul Jamo Extended-A'}
\doprmb{55216}{55295}{'Hangul Jamo Extended-B'}
\doprmb{44032}{55215}{'Hangul Syllables'}
\doprmb{68864}{68927}{'Hanifi Rohingya'}
\doprmb{5920}{5951}{'Hanunoo'}
\doprmb{67808}{67839}{'Hatran'}
\doprmb{1424}{1535}{'Hebrew'}
\doprmb{56192}{56319}{'High Private Use Surrogates'}
\doprmb{55296}{56191}{'High Surrogates'}
\doprmb{12352}{12447}{'Hiragana'}
\doprmb{12272}{12287}{'Ideographic Description Characters'}
\doprmb{94176}{94207}{'Ideographic Symbols and Punctuation'}
\doprmb{67648}{67679}{'Imperial Aramaic'}
\doprmb{126064}{126143}{'Indic Siyaq Numbers'}
\doprmb{68448}{68479}{'Inscriptional Pahlavi'}
\doprmb{68416}{68447}{'Inscriptional Parthian'}
\doprmb{592}{687}{'IPA Extensions'}
\doprmb{43392}{43487}{'Javanese'}
\doprmb{69760}{69839}{'Kaithi'}
\doprmb{110848}{110895}{'Kana Extended-A'}
\doprmb{110592}{110847}{'Kana Supplement'}
\doprmb{12688}{12703}{'Kanbun'}
\doprmb{12032}{12255}{'Kangxi Radicals'}
\doprmb{3200}{3327}{'Kannada'}
\doprmb{12448}{12543}{'Katakana'}
\doprmb{12784}{12799}{'Katakana Phonetic Extensions'}
\doprmb{43264}{43311}{'Kayah Li'}
\doprmb{68096}{68191}{'Kharoshthi'}
\doprmb{101120}{101631}{'Khitan Small Script'}
\doprmb{6016}{6143}{'Khmer'}
\doprmb{6624}{6655}{'Khmer Symbols'}
\doprmb{70144}{70223}{'Khojki'}
\doprmb{70320}{70399}{'Khudawadi'}
\doprmb{3712}{3839}{'Lao'}
\doprmb{7680}{7935}{'Latin Extended Additional'}
\doprmb{256}{383}{'Latin Extended-A'}
\doprmb{384}{591}{'Latin Extended-B'}
\doprmb{11360}{11391}{'Latin Extended-C'}
\doprmb{42784}{43007}{'Latin Extended-D'}
\doprmb{43824}{43887}{'Latin Extended-E'}
\doprmb{128}{255}{'Latin-1 Supplement[h]'}
\doprmb{7168}{7247}{'Lepcha'}
\doprmb{8448}{8527}{'Letterlike Symbols'}
\doprmb{6400}{6479}{'Limbu'}
\doprmb{67072}{67455}{'Linear A'}
\doprmb{65664}{65791}{'Linear B Ideograms'}
\doprmb{65536}{65663}{'Linear B Syllabary'}
\doprmb{42192}{42239}{'Lisu'}
\doprmb{73648}{73663}{'Lisu Supplement'}
\doprmb{56320}{57343}{'Low Surrogates'}
\doprmb{66176}{66207}{'Lycian'}
\doprmb{67872}{67903}{'Lydian'}
\doprmb{69968}{70015}{'Mahajani'}
\doprmb{126976}{127023}{'Mahjong Tiles'}
\doprmb{73440}{73471}{'Makasar'}
\doprmb{3328}{3455}{'Malayalam'}
\doprmb{2112}{2143}{'Mandaic'}
\doprmb{68288}{68351}{'Manichaean'}
\doprmb{72816}{72895}{'Marchen'}
\doprmb{72960}{73055}{'Masaram Gondi'}
\doprmb{119808}{120831}{'Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols'}
\doprmb{8704}{8959}{'Mathematical Operators'}
\doprmb{119520}{119551}{'Mayan Numerals'}
\doprmb{93760}{93855}{'Medefaidrin'}
\doprmb{43968}{44031}{'Meetei Mayek'}
\doprmb{43744}{43775}{'Meetei Mayek Extensions'}
\doprmb{124928}{125151}{'Mende Kikakui'}
\doprmb{68000}{68095}{'Meroitic Cursive'}
\doprmb{67968}{67999}{'Meroitic Hieroglyphs'}
\doprmb{93952}{94111}{'Miao'}
\doprmb{10176}{10223}{'Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A'}
\doprmb{10624}{10751}{'Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B'}
\doprmb{9728}{9983}{'Miscellaneous Symbols'}
\doprmb{11008}{11263}{'Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows'}
\doprmb{127744}{128511}{'Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs'}
\doprmb{8960}{9215}{'Miscellaneous Technical'}
\doprmb{71168}{71263}{'Modi'}
\doprmb{42752}{42783}{'Modifier Tone Letters'}
\doprmb{6144}{6319}{'Mongolian'}
\doprmb{71264}{71295}{'Mongolian Supplement'}
\doprmb{92736}{92783}{'Mro'}
\doprmb{70272}{70319}{'Multani'}
\doprmb{119040}{119295}{'Musical Symbols'}
\doprmb{4096}{4255}{'Myanmar'}
\doprmb{43616}{43647}{'Myanmar Extended-A'}
\doprmb{43488}{43519}{'Myanmar Extended-B'}
\doprmb{67712}{67759}{'Nabataean'}
\doprmb{72096}{72191}{'Nandinagari'}
\doprmb{6528}{6623}{'New Tai Lue'}
\doprmb{70656}{70783}{'Newa'}
\doprmb{1984}{2047}{'NKo'}
\doprmb{8528}{8591}{'Number Forms'}
\doprmb{110960}{111359}{'Nushu'}
\doprmb{123136}{123215}{'Nyiakeng Puachue Hmong'}
\doprmb{5760}{5791}{'Ogham'}
\doprmb{7248}{7295}{'Ol Chiki'}
\doprmb{68736}{68863}{'Old Hungarian'}
\doprmb{66304}{66351}{'Old Italic'}
\doprmb{68224}{68255}{'Old North Arabian'}
\doprmb{66384}{66431}{'Old Permic'}
\doprmb{66464}{66527}{'Old Persian'}
\doprmb{69376}{69423}{'Old Sogdian'}
\doprmb{68192}{68223}{'Old South Arabian'}
\doprmb{68608}{68687}{'Old Turkic'}
\doprmb{9280}{9311}{'Optical Character Recognition'}
\doprmb{2816}{2943}{'Oriya'}
\doprmb{128592}{128639}{'Ornamental Dingbats'}
\doprmb{66736}{66815}{'Osage'}
\doprmb{66688}{66735}{'Osmanya'}
\doprmb{126208}{126287}{'Ottoman Siyaq Numbers'}
\doprmb{92928}{93071}{'Pahawh Hmong'}
\doprmb{67680}{67711}{'Palmyrene'}
\doprmb{72384}{72447}{'Pau Cin Hau'}
\doprmb{43072}{43135}{'Phags-pa'}
\doprmb{66000}{66047}{'Phaistos Disc'}
\doprmb{67840}{67871}{'Phoenician'}
\doprmb{7424}{7551}{'Phonetic Extensions'}
\doprmb{7552}{7615}{'Phonetic Extensions Supplement'}
\doprmb{127136}{127231}{'Playing Cards'}
\doprmb{57344}{63743}{'Private Use Area'}
\doprmb{68480}{68527}{'Psalter Pahlavi'}
\doprmb{43312}{43359}{'Rejang'}
\doprmb{69216}{69247}{'Rumi Numeral Symbols'}
\doprmb{5792}{5887}{'Runic'}
\doprmb{2048}{2111}{'Samaritan'}
\doprmb{43136}{43231}{'Saurashtra'}
\doprmb{70016}{70111}{'Sharada'}
\doprmb{66640}{66687}{'Shavian'}
\doprmb{113824}{113839}{'Shorthand Format Controls'}
\doprmb{71040}{71167}{'Siddham'}
\doprmb{3456}{3583}{'Sinhala'}
\doprmb{70112}{70143}{'Sinhala Archaic Numbers'}
\doprmb{65104}{65135}{'Small Form Variants'}
\doprmb{110896}{110959}{'Small Kana Extension'}
\doprmb{69424}{69487}{'Sogdian'}
\doprmb{69840}{69887}{'Sora Sompeng'}
\doprmb{72272}{72367}{'Soyombo'}
\doprmb{688}{767}{'Spacing Modifier Letters'}
\doprmb{65520}{65535}{'Specials'}
\doprmb{7040}{7103}{'Sundanese'}
\doprmb{7360}{7375}{'Sundanese Supplement'}
\doprmb{8304}{8351}{'Superscripts and Subscripts'}
\doprmb{10224}{10239}{'Supplemental Arrows-A'}
\doprmb{10496}{10623}{'Supplemental Arrows-B'}
\doprmb{129024}{129279}{'Supplemental Arrows-C'}
\doprmb{10752}{11007}{'Supplemental Mathematical Operators'}
\doprmb{11776}{11903}{'Supplemental Punctuation'}
\doprmb{129280}{129535}{'Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs'}
\doprmb{983040}{1048575}{'Supplementary Private Use Area-A'}
\doprmb{1048576}{1114111}{'Supplementary Private Use Area-B'}
\doprmb{120832}{121519}{'Sutton SignWriting'}
\doprmb{43008}{43055}{'Syloti Nagri'}
\doprmb{129648}{129791}{'Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A'}
\doprmb{129792}{130047}{'Symbols for Legacy Computing'}
\doprmb{1792}{1871}{'Syriac'}
\doprmb{2144}{2159}{'Syriac Supplement'}
\doprmb{5888}{5919}{'Tagalog'}
\doprmb{5984}{6015}{'Tagbanwa'}
\doprmb{917504}{917631}{'Tags'}
\doprmb{6480}{6527}{'Tai Le'}
\doprmb{6688}{6831}{'Tai Tham'}
\doprmb{43648}{43743}{'Tai Viet'}
\doprmb{119552}{119647}{'Tai Xuan Jing Symbols'}
\doprmb{71296}{71375}{'Takri'}
\doprmb{2944}{3071}{'Tamil'}
\doprmb{73664}{73727}{'Tamil Supplement'}
\doprmb{94208}{100351}{'Tangut'}
\doprmb{100352}{101119}{'Tangut Components'}
\doprmb{101632}{101775}{'Tangut Supplement'}
\doprmb{3072}{3199}{'Telugu'}
\doprmb{1920}{1983}{'Thaana'}
\doprmb{3584}{3711}{'Thai'}
\doprmb{3840}{4095}{'Tibetan'}
\doprmb{11568}{11647}{'Tifinagh'}
\doprmb{70784}{70879}{'Tirhuta'}
\doprmb{128640}{128767}{'Transport and Map Symbols'}
\doprmb{66432}{66463}{'Ugaritic'}
\doprmb{5120}{5759}{'Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics'}
\doprmb{6320}{6399}{'Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended'}
\doprmb{42240}{42559}{'Vai'}
\doprmb{65024}{65039}{'Variation Selectors'}
\doprmb{917760}{917999}{'Variation Selectors Supplement'}
\doprmb{7376}{7423}{'Vedic Extensions'}
\doprmb{65040}{65055}{'Vertical Forms'}
\doprmb{123584}{123647}{'Wancho'}
\doprmb{71840}{71935}{'Warang Citi'}
\doprmb{69248}{69311}{'Yezidi'}
\doprmb{42128}{42191}{'Yi Radicals'}
\doprmb{40960}{42127}{'Yi Syllables'}
\doprmb{19904}{19967}{'Yijing Hexagram Symbols'}
\doprmb{72192}{72271}{'Zanabazar Square'}
\directlua{printglyphliste()}
\doclosemyfont
}





\nc\doopenmyfont[1]{%
\directlua{openmyfont('#1')}}


\nc\doclosemyfont{%
\directlua{closemyfont()}}







%===============================
\nc\tag[1]{{\color{blue}\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small\fcolorbox{blue!80}{blue!5}{#1}}~~}

\newcounter{fontcounter}

%===============





\begin{document}


\nc\wiafshowblocks[4]{%1=path,2=ext,3=file,4=font
\expandafter\newfontface\csname f#4\endcsname{#3}[
  Path=#1,
  Extension=#2,
  UprightFont=*,
]
\csname f#4\endcsname
\togglefalse{printastring}
\wiafprintchars{#1#3#2}% unicode blocks, then glyph list
}



\wiafshowblocks{c:/windows/fonts/}{.ttf}{\detokenize{LinBiolinum_R_G}}{lbgr}

\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer*

For reference, a Lualatex solution.

Lualatex has access to glyph names and numbers (and other things), so, by using lua code to access the font structure and looping through the glyphs, we can see what is in a font, via a glyph-list view:

[image: list]

[image: listb]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\pagecolor{brown!3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newtoggle{printastring}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\newfontfamily\flab{Noto Serif}% for labels

\let\nc\newcommand

\nc\mypathname{C:/Windows/Fonts/}
\nc\myext{.ttf}
\nc\myfilename{xxx}
\nc\myfont{\mypathname\myfilename\myext}


\nc\fstartrange{97}
\nc\fendrange{122}

\begin{luacode}
    function printmysample(mystart, myfinish)
--  tex.sprint(myfont)
--local f = fontloader.open(myfont)
local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)
--   tex.sprint('Sample\\\\')
--tex.sprint(f.glyphmax .. ' glyphs\\\\')
for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode >= mystart ) then
      if (glyphs[i].unicode <= myfinish ) then
                tex.sprint("\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
           end
           end
   end
end
--fontloader.close(f)

    end
\end{luacode}

\nc\doprintmysample[2]{%
\begin{quotation}
\noindent\directlua{printmysample(#1 ,#2)}
\end{quotation}
\par\bigskip
}






\begin{luacode}
    function openmyfont(xxx)
      f = fontloader.open(xxx)
      tex.sprint("{\\flab\\section{" .. f.fullname .. "}}")
      tex.sprint("{\\flab " .. f.fullname .. ", " .. f.glyphcnt .. " chars}\\par\\bigskip")
 end
\end{luacode}


\begin{luacode}
    function closemyfont(xxx)
        fontloader.close(f)
  end
\end{luacode}

%=================

%=================
\begin{luacode}
    function printglyphliste()
    tex.sprint("\\subsection{Glyph List}")
    tex.sprint("\\begin{multicols}{6}")
local glyphs = {}
local ck = 0
local pc = 0
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)

for i = 1, #glyphs do
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
--              tex.sprint("\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "\\ ")
                    tex.sprint("{\\centering\\noindent\\begin{tabular}{c}\\huge{\\color{blue}\\Uchar" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}\\\\ { \\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny\\detokenize{" .. glyphs[i].name .. "}}\\\\ { \\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny\\colorbox{blue!8}{" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}}\\\\\\hline\\end{tabular} \\par}")
   end
end
    tex.sprint("{\\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\\tiny [End of List]}\\par")
    tex.sprint("\\end{multicols}")
end
\end{luacode}






\nc\wiafprintchars[1]{%
\doopenmyfont{#1}
\doprintmysample{\fstartrange}{\fendrange}
\directlua{printglyphliste()}
\doclosemyfont
}





\nc\doopenmyfont[1]{%
\directlua{openmyfont('#1')}}


\nc\doclosemyfont{%
\directlua{closemyfont()}}







%===============================
\nc\tag[1]{{\color{blue}\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small\fcolorbox{blue!80}{blue!5}{#1}}~~}

\newcounter{fontcounter}

%===============





\begin{document}


\nc\wiafshowblocks[4]{%1=path,2=ext,3=file,4=font
\expandafter\newfontface\csname f#4\endcsname{#3}[
  Path=#1,
  Extension=#2,
  UprightFont=*,
]
\csname f#4\endcsname
\togglefalse{printastring}
\wiafprintchars{#1#3#2}% unicode blocks, then glyph list
}



\wiafshowblocks{c:/windows/fonts/}{.ttf}{\detokenize{LinBiolinum_R_G}}{lbgr}

\end{document}
```

Code somewhat adapted from various other answers on this site.

Removed long-winded code that printed by Unicode codeblock, to get it under the 30k char limit (until I can shrink it).