# How to make all staff notation in LaTeX?

Tags: unicode, music, musixtex

I want to use LaTeX, to make Unicode of staff notation!
Look at the picture below:
[image]

All I want to do is LaTeX + Unicode!
I hope you can make it!
The Unicode URL is here, go check it out: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644255/11604

Comment: your question is not very clear, do you mean you want to  typeset a unicode font chart, as you show, or do you mean you want to use Unicode input to set music, in the latter case unicode isn't the main complication you want a music package for positoning in music staves etc

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D122}{\bassclef}

\begin{document}

\bassclef \Large\verb| U+1D122|

\end{document}
```

[image]