# \XeTeXglyph for Math Mode (alternative?)

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, fontspec, unicode

Is there an alternative for `\XeTeXglyph` that works in math mode? Or is there a way `\XeTeXglyph` itself can work in math mode?

I want to access a specific glyph as a math symbol (UF091F specifically) in Minion Math using `\XeTeXglyph` but each time I try an error comes up saying 
`! You can't use \XeTeXglyph in math mode.`

Using `\symbol{######}` works fine in LuaLaTeX but I think because the glyph I want is a 6 digit number, in XeTeX it outputs `! Bad character code (######)` (where ###### is the symbol number [as found using this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98208/70174). Hence why I'm trying to use `\XeTeXglyph`, unless there actually *is* a way of using `\symbol` for that glyph without that error?

Comment: I'd say `\text{\XeTeXglyph...}` should work (if you load `amsmath`).

Comment: @egreg yes but would that give the proper spacing for a math symbol?

Comment: `\mathrel{\text{\XeTeXglyph...}}` or `\mathbin` or one of the other primitives.

Comment: You might want to look if your symbol can be found in [unimath-symbols](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a glyph called by index with a font I have, in this case XITS Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\newfontfamily{\test}{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

{\test\XeTeXglyph4491}

$A\mathrel{\text{\test\XeTeXglyph4491}}B$

$A\mathbin{\text{\test\XeTeXglyph4491}}B$

$A\mathpunct{\text{\test\XeTeXglyph4491}}B$

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll want to make a macro.

[image]

On the other hand, either `\symbol{985375}` or `\symbol{"F091F}` should work, provided you hide them inside `\text`. I happen to have a font that has a glyph in that position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\newfontfamily{\chn}{HanaMinPlus}

\begin{document}

{\chn\symbol{"F091F}}---{\chn\symbol{985375}}

$A\mathrel{\text{\chn\symbol{"F091F}}}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer to my question technically... Problem is, seems like my glyph table [from here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/generating-a-table-of-glyphs-with-xetex) doesn't link to the right glyph (it says 333 but when I put that in my doc it outputs the wrong symbol!). So let's say I want to stick to `\symbol`; when I put it in `\text{\symbol{985375}}` it outputs the symbol ☒ (guess that's an error; its supposed to be a lambda bar), and when I remove the `\text` it shows nothing except error message `Bad character code (985375)` :(

Comment: @airatin -- two forms of "lambda bar" should be in the xits/stix fonts: `\lambdabar` with a horizontal stroke and `\lambdaslash` with a slanted stroke.  (i haven't checked the font, but since i was responsible for the names, that is what i found in my authoritative reference table.  `\lambdaslash` should be at U+019B but `\lambdabar` is in the private use area, so there's no telling what conflicts there might be with other font definitions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, however I do want to use Minion Math for the lambda bar symbol since it already is provided in it; I'm trying to avoid using other fonts unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @airatin -- according to the unicode manual (5.0), "the entire plane 15, with the exception of the noncharacters U+FFFFE and U+FFFFF, is defined to be the supplementary private use area a."  access to the private use area, in my (limited-mainly-to-theory) experience can be a touchy matter.  if there is any documentation on this with respect to minion math, it would be a good idea to read it carefully.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Using LuaLaTeX I get the correct output with that same symbol number, even though it is Private Use. It would be nice if XeLaTeX would allow the same :( also Typoma (creator of Minion Math) has nothing on their website for LuaTeX/XeTeX, so I could email the owner and see if he has any solutions. But still this same syntax should be allowed in XeTeX the way it is in LuaTeX :(

Comment: @airatin -- your observation regarding the syntax in xetex sounds good to me.  you might look at the [archives of the xetex mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/) to see if someone has already asked it, and, if not, send the inquiry yourself, to `xetex@tug.org`.