# How can I use \XeTeXcountglyphs\font in a pgf \foreach macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xetex

## Problem

I keep getting:

```
You can't use `\XeTeXcountglyphs` in vertical mode.
```

## Attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\maxstep{\XeTeXcountglyphs\font}
\foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
    \XeTeXglyph\charstep
}%
\end{document}
```

Note that I have since changed `\pgfmathsetmacro` to `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` so that I can type the following in my document and it makes sense (otherwise you get something like 2625.01; fractions of glyphs do not make sense):

```
 Number of glyphs: \maxstep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` wants to see an explicit number, not an internal register. So `\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font` would do, but it doesn't for another reason: trying to print the glyph corresponding to the highest count results in an error.

Solution: step back by 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro\maxstep{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1}
\foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
    \XeTeXglyph\charstep\space\space
}

\end{document}
```

The first `\space` is swallowed by `\XeTeXglyph`, the second one survives and spaces the result.

[image]

Comment: I've incorporated this into my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235125/13552

Comment: A consolation tick for being _so slow_ to post an answer:-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\edef`, however the indexing is 0 based so you need to reduce by 1 or you
get an error while accessing the last slot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\edef\maxstep{\the\numexpr\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1\relax}

\typeout{maxstep is \maxstep}

\foreach \charstep in {0,...,\maxstep}{%
    \XeTeXglyph\charstep
}%
\end{document}
```

the above is error free, although I don't show the image, the result is a little
overfull

```
Overfull \hbox (4178.74983pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14
```

Comment: I got rid of the Overfull `\hbox`with by changing the line `\XeTeXglyph\charstep` to `\XeTeXglyph\charstep{}\space`

Comment: @macmadness86 yes sure, I assumed you knew what final layout you wanted, a space or `\\ ` or whatever, so I just left it as in the original.

Comment: Ah ok. I did feel like I was "preaching to the choir" when I wrote that. You clearly would be one to know how to remedy that error! Also, I enjoyed the humor (a "little" overfull—just 4000+ points too wide:)