# How can I extract a character code (code point) from a character slot in a given font? [XeTeX]

Tags: xetex, unicode

## Question

I am wondering if there is a way to provide the `\XeTeXglyph` as input and get the the character code (preferably in hexidecimal) as output.

## Situation

I've been doing many experiments with
[Generating a table of glyphs with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/generating-a-table-of-glyphs-with-xetex/235125#235125). The XeTeX reference manual mentions a few commands:

According to the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetexref?lang=en), you can look up characters by

- `\XeTeXglyph` ⟨glyph slot⟩
- `\XeTeXglyphname` ⟨font⟩ ⟨glyph slot⟩
- `\XeTeXglyphindex` "⟨glyph name⟩" ⟨space⟩ or \relaxx
- `\XeTeXcharglyph` ⟨char code⟩

This would be an insanely useful feature.

## Related Questions

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-font-supports

Comment: No, there isn't. Two character codes could point to the same glyph.

Comment: @egreg disappointed face ಠ_ಠ. Two character codes point to the same glyph? really? Don't you mean that one glyph could have different representations (roman, italic, bold, etc.)

Comment: @egreg: What about Lua(La)TeX?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence I think it's the same problem.

Comment: @macmadness86 egreg means that fonts can reuse a glyph for various (unicode) symbols. After all a lot of symbols look quite similar. A font can e.g use the same glyph for U+0162 and U+021A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible.

Some glyphs could but used for multiple unicode slots.

---

*Note:* It seems perfectly reasonable to create a function that  acquires multiple code points, should the same glyph be used in multiple code points. Maybe someone will make this possible someday.