# How can I typeset magic the gathering symbols using the pifont package in latex?

Tags: fonts, errors, symbols, compilation-error, pifont

I am trying to use the /pifont package to typeset magic the gathering symbols and keep getting the following error:

`Font U/magic/m/n/12=magic at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \Pisymbol{magic}{66}`.

Below is my code:

```
\title{MTG}
\author{Michael Dykes}

\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{magic}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{magic}{m}{n}{<-> magic}{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\Pisymbol{magic}{66}


\end{document}
```

I am not sure what to do to fix this. I downloaded the pifont package and installed it in

```
/usr/share/local/texmf
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need a dingbat font (also called 'pifont' because it usually has Greek letters for math) that contains the symbols. `pifont` package lets you access a specific character in a (Type1) font, like the Delta (Δ) in the `psy` (Symbol) font family. What were you looking at (what font file?) that made you think the character you want is in position 66?

Comment: There's a (truetype) dingbat font at: (http://www.thealmightyguru.com/GameFonts/Series-MagicTheGathering.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .ttf truetype font installed as a system font needs `fontspec` package and compiling with either xelatex/lualatex.

The dingbat font just replaces (some of) the ordinary letters on the keyboard with symbols. So, when the font is active in the document, typing `B` will give you the symbol sitting in position 66.

[image: dingbat]

MWE

```
%Code adapted from:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23863/generating-a-table-of-glyphs-with-xetex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontface\fmedi{MagicMedieval}
\newfontface\fsymb{MagicSymbols}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{multido}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\fmedi
\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{"FF}{% 
  \iffontchar\font\i
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \symbol{\i}\endgraf
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

A B C D E
\fsymb
\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{"FF}{% 
  \iffontchar\font\i
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \symbol{\i}\endgraf
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

A B C \symbol{71} \symbol{79} \symbol{82}
\end{document}

Fonts from:
http://www.thealmightyguru.com/GameFonts/Series-MagicTheGathering.html
```

The code shows how to make a list of characters in a font, and is adapted from another answer.

Comment: I realize this i probably a stupid question, but once I download the fonts listed above, where do I put them so I don't keep getting the  fonts not found error?

Comment: in answer to your question about position 66, I have almost no experience using fonts systems in latex in this manner and was looking at the full font list from all LaTeX fonts.

Comment: Installing fonts depends on your system. In Windows, I right-click and select "Install for all users". With system fonts, you will need to compile with xelatex or lualatex, using `fontspec` package. Presumably, when you say "LaTeX fonts", you are referring to legacy 7-bit and 8-bit fonts under pdflatex, like `lmr` and suchlike. I don't know if anyone has made a Type1 font from the ttf version.

Answer (score 0):

The package `pifont` alone is not sufficient. Simply put the contents of https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/magic (`magic.mf` and `magic12.mf`) into the same directory as your input file and then run [pdf]latex.