# OpenType case-senstive forms break microtype's protrusion for hyphens

Tags: punctuation, microtype, opentype, protrusion, textcase

By enabling the OpenType feature case-senstive forms (`[Letters=Uppercase]`), vertically lifted brackets, hyphens, or parentheses for example) via setmainfont with fontspec, I loose the protrusion for word break hyphen glyphs done by microtype:

```
\setmainfont[Letters=Uppercase,StylisticSet={02,04}]{ESAllianz}
\microtypesetup{activate={true,nocompatibility},final,babel=true,factor=1000,stretch=20,shrink=20}
```

Since I use LuaLaTex, I found [microtype's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) the following on page 19:

> The situation is different with LuaTeX and XeTeX, however: the default inheritance settings only contain those glyhps that can safely be assumed to exist in any font; but since OpenType fonts may contain many more glyphs for different scripts (languages), it is quite probable that font-specific settings are necessary, which should be specified in the font’s configuration file (see next section).

Indeed, the standard hyphen is replaced by a case-sensitive hyphen (while still being the same character in Unicode: `U+002D`).

I tried with `\DeclareCharacterInheritance{family={ES Allianz}}{\symbol{"002D}=-}` Where `\symbol{"002D}` is the LaTeX command printing a hyphen, to inherit the protrusion settings of a non-uppercase hyphen `-`.

Desired outcome: case-sensitive forms in my text, and still correctly protuded hyphens for word breaks.

I tried also to `\SetProtrusion{{\symbol{"002D} ={500,500}}}`, but that didn't work.

See the images for the difference:

[image: without case-sensitive forms, but with correct protrusion for the hyphen]

↑ without case-sensitive forms, but with correct protrusion for the hyphen

[image: with case-sensitive forms, but without protrusions for the hypen]

↑ with case-sensitive forms, but without protrusions for the hypen

What do I need to do? I am not experienced with microtype's configuration files (on macOS, MacTeX 2023). Thanks in advance!

---

**Progress**

I found the correct glyph identifier, using [generate a table of all the possible glyphs of a given font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23874/296131):

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ES Allianz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{multido}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{10}
\multido{\i=0+1}{"100000}{
  \iffontchar\font\i
    \makebox[3em][l]{\i}%
    \symbol{\i}\endgraf
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

(raised the hex number to enlarge glyph count)

And I can print the correct case-sensitive hyphen by using `\symbol{983167}` (identifier `983167` in the printed glyph table).

Now I try using `\DeclareCharacterInheritance` the following, where the identifier `45` is the regular hyphen:

```
\DeclareCharacterInheritance{encoding={OT1,T1,TS1},family={*}}{\symbol{45} = \symbol{983167}}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, and I don't know why. I try to put it on various locations in the preamble, but it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
# - \SetProtrusion{encoding={OT1,T1,TS1},family={*},series={*},size={*}}{\symbol{983167} ={1000,1000},} %over-exaggerated to make sure it is visible
```

Doesn't work either. It does work with regular glyphs, given in its true Unicode Char value, like with for example a literal `e`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It is possible to request specific font OpenType glyphs, in microtype, by using the exact glyph name. In the situation mentioned, the font glyph might be `hyphen.case`. The microtype config file would name it something such as `/hyphen.case`. Not sure of the syntax. Underlying problem, which is why microtype does not automatically find the glyph you need: In another font, that glyph might be named `hyphen.raised` or something else. So you would need to inspect the font. There is a lot of non-standard usage in OpenType.

Comment: You are right about the glyph name in the font I use: `hyphen.case`. The problem there is not a comment in (Lua)TeX to print that/ `\hyphen` works, but `\hyphen.case` prints a '-.case'. I also tried to make a `\newfontfamily` environment, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Printing the case-sensitive hyphen: `\symbol{983167}` (identifier `983167` in the glyph table) does work now. See edited post.

Comment: don't use the command `\symbol` in the settings, but just the glyph id number (prefixed with `"` for hexadecimal, or with `'` for octal), see microtype.pdf, section 5. (I can't test it though, because I don't have the font.)