# xdvipdfmx parse error when using particular font with fontspec

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, xdvipdfmx

I am using the font `IM FELL English PRO` ([open-source otf here](http://iginomarini.com/fell/wp-content/uploads/IMFellTypesClass.zip)) via the `fontspec` package, and when I tried typesetting the characters `\"{a}`, `\'{n}` or `\"{o}`, I got this error:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Type2 Charstring Parser: Parsing charstring failed: (status=-1, stack=5)
Output file removed.
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{IM FELL English PRO}
\begin{document}
\'{n}
\end{document}
```

I am using XeTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 and `fontspec` version 2.4a. Another user also got the same error using LuaTeX with this MWE.

Those characters do exist in this font. There are other characters that give this error (e.g. [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201595/accented-letters-with-im-fell-fonts)), but not all accented characters have the problem; e.g. `\"{u}` is ok. The error also goes away if I change to another font, such as `Arial`. There is another [similar thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194808/an-error-with-xelatex-and-fontspec) where the OP there got the same error with some fonts but not others. It was suggested there for various reasons that I should start a new question.

The font developer Igino Marini told me the font had been generated in FontLab Studio and had passed the Microsoft Font Validator, and no problems have been reported to him outside of LaTeX.

Many thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I get the same error with LuaLaTeX. On the other hand, `otfinfo` reports the existence of `nacute` in the font.

Comment: Note that U+0144 LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE does exist in the font, which I checked with `fontforge`; I guess it's the culprit. Also `\iffontchar\font"0144` returns true.

Comment: I tried with TL 2012, which predates the adoption of the HarfBuzz library; again the error is the same: ** WARNING ** "seac" character deprecated in Type 2 charstring.
** ERROR ** Type2 Charstring Parser: Parsing charstring failed: (status=-1, stack=5)

Comment: @egreg I discovered that I can get all the characters to work by [re-exporting from FontForge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203153/12420) -- this might offer some clues.