# How to know the correct name for an installed font to be passed as the argument of \setmainfont?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have just installed a font called "28 Days Later" from [www.1001freefonts.com](http://www.1001freefonts.com/) but now I have a problem because the following code snippet does not compile, it produces some errors, roughly saying that "The 28 Days Later font could not be found.".

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{28 Days Later}

\begin{document}
Oh my ghost
\end{document}
```

So, how do we  know the correct name for an installed font to be passed as the argument of `\setmainfont`?

Comment: Something might be wrong with that particular font.

Comment: @Werner: It is something wrong, as the compilation fails with `28 Days Later.ttf`, but not with some other arbitrary one

Comment: Compiling with LuaLaTeX works?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Nope, `lualatex` fails too

Comment: @ChristianHupfer LuaLaTeX recognises it in my case.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Really? Well, I tested it in an early stage, perhaps there was another error

Comment: Yangchen Lin’s answer of 15 Sept 2014, at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203153/7883, although it’s an answer to a somewhat problem, works here too.  Just open the font in FontForge and select “Generate Fonts” under the “File” menu.  You don’t even have to fix the em-size as FontForge will suggest, though you may wish to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (unfortunately) not working with the `28 Days Later` font, since the `xelatex` compilation breaks with some `error 11`.

The principal way is to use `\setmainfont{fontname}[options]`

The manual of `fontspec` states, that following font options must be set if the font is specified by filename (and not fontname)

- BoldFont
- ItalicFont
- BoldItalicFont

Since `28 Days Later.ttf` fails, I used `winnie.ttf` from the same website, for demonstration only and principal pathway, but it's not the solution to the question, of course.

---

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}



\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{winnie}[
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=winnie,
BoldFont=winnie,
ItalicFont=winnie,
BoldItalicFont=winnie,
SmallCapsFont=winnie]



\begin{document}
Oh my ghost
\end{document}
```

[image]