# Historic font and missing ligatures

Tags: fontspec, ligatures

I am trying to compose a sort of old-style book. I would like to use a specific historical font for the entire text. This font includes ligature glyphs for: `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffl`, and `st` (see Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ObwD.png) for the italic style).

[image: Map of characters]

Unfortunately, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX seem not to recognize the presence of ligatures. I tried the following simple code.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Required,%
Common,Contextual,Rare,Historic,TeX}]{Historical-FellTypeItalic}

\begin{document}
ff fi fl ffl st
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the LaTeX result is without ligatures (the same occurs with the light style of the font). On  the other hand, different fonts (e.g. Linux Libertine) work correctly. I tried also to install the font in LaTeX system but I did not obtain any result (the font works but not the ligatures).

Do you know any solution?

Another (and secondary) question. Some interesting glyph (as `ct`, `us`, and `as`) are present. I have no idea, how to integrate them in the LaTeX code. I would like to type words using those glyphs without particular declarations.

For your information: I use a fully updated TeXLive on Windows 10 (x64).

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for all answers. It works fine, but I would deepen the matter with the LuaLaTeX code.
If I had more than a single font in use (e.g. ITALIC.otf and ROMAN.otf), how could  I have adapted the Lua-code for lacking glyphs in different fonts?
Let me explain through an example:
The ligature glyph `is` (uchar(916)) exists for ITALIC.otf but not for ROMAN.otf. In this way, the simplify code:

```
% all your LuaLaTeX-code
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont=ITALIC.otf]{ROMAN.otf}
\begin{document}
is \textit{is}
\end{document}
```

produces a PDF uniquely with the italic `is` (the roman `is` is missed). I suppose, that LaTeX tries to search the ROMAN glyph uchar(916) instead of inserting the ROMAN glyphs of `i` and `s`.
Do a solution exist? Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: Is use of XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX required?

Comment: If it works with other fonts, then the problem is with your font. My guess is that it doesn't have OpenType features. But it's not possible for us to answer this conclusively without access to your font.

Comment: Get the Fell types, with OpenType features, from http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/  Then it will suffice to use `\setmainfont{IM FELL English PRO}[Ligatures=Rare]` (but there is no discretionary st ligature, only ct, as, ij, is, us…).

Comment: I tried your suggestion (changing the font). Unfortunately, the IGINOMARINI fonts has a lot of problems with diacritic signs (acute, grave, and circumflex accent), that are essential in Italian.

Comment: @GranducaPlinio - Regarding the questions you raise in the follow-up comments: The reason I found it necessary to come up with some highly font-specific Lua code in my answer is that the name table of the font `Historical-FellTypeItalic` is, to put it politely, highly non-standard. If you have other fonts whose name tables are also non-standard, more specialized Lua code will almost certainly be needed to activate their ligatures. The real solution, in my view, would be to clean up and re-release the fonts, now standard-adherent name tables.

Comment: @Mico - Are you suggesting to work directly on the font through a font editor like FontForge? Probably, I'll have to study that manual.

Comment: @GranducaPlinio - I'm afraid I'm not sure what my recommendation would be regarding what you may want to do if several fonts have messed-up name tables. (My LuaLaTeX-based answer was tailored to one specific font.) I also don't know if FontForge is the best tool for cleaning up a messed-up name table. (There's probably more than one may to mess up a name table, right?!) Maybe the best thing to do, at first, is to contact the authors and maintainers of the fonts and -- assuming they can be identified -- ask them if they happen to have a version of the font(s) with standard name tables.

Comment: There’s a solution to the problem with accents at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203153/7883

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with this font -- as far as its ligatures are concerned -- is that the ligature names in the internal font table are, shall we say, utterly non-standard. For instance, instead of going with standard names such as `f_f` and `f_f_i` for the ligatures, a search with the FontForge app reveals that the font uses the names `Omega` and `approxequal`. No joke!! (A not-uncharitable assessment of the situation might be that the font's name correspondence table got garbled at some point prior to compilation.)

Given this situation, it's probably not a surprise that LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX are not able to figure out the name mappings without special help.

Using LuaLaTeX, I can think of *two solutions* to this mess. The first solution creates a custom "feature file", which informs the system about the ligature names actually used by the font. The second, shown further below, uses LuaTeX functionality directly to get the ligatures working.

---

With the help of FontForge I was able to find the "names" for all ten ligatures. These names are used to set up a so-called "Feature File", named `addligs_HFTI.fea`, that can be loaded via an instruction such as `\addfontfeatures{FeatureFile=addligs_HFTI.fea}`.

Unfortunately, despite having found the font's ligature "names" for all ten ligatures, this approach succeeds in activating only four of them (`ct`, `ff`, `ffi`, and `ffl`, to be specific). Maybe something else got garbled as well when the font was compiled?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{addligs_HFTI.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub a s   by summation;
    sub i s   by Delta;
    sub u s   by divide;
    sub c t   by plusminus;
    sub f f   by Omega;
    sub f i   by fi;
    sub f l   by fl;
    sub f f i by approxequal;
    sub f f l by radical;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\liglist{as is ct ff fi fl ffi ffl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=Common}
\setmainfont{Historical-FellTypeItalic}

\begin{document}
w/o ligatures: \liglist

\addfontfeatures{FeatureFile=addligs_HFTI.fea}
with ligatures: \liglist
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*. Given that the feature file approach doesn't succeed in activating all ten ligatures present in the font, the following solution, which is entirely coded in Lua, may be worth considering. It uses the `process_input_buffer` callback to run a function that performs a "brute force" substitution of the ten character pairs and triples with the corresponding glyphs that represent the ligated versions. (Full disclosure: The code used below gratefully uses code originally provided by @michal.h21 in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262631/5001) to my recent posting, entitled [LuaLaTeX: How to use a \char directive inside a string.gsub function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262630/5001)) Observe that special care had to be taken to ensure that any LaTeX macros that may include strings such as "ff", "fi", etc aren't caught up in the brute-force substitution.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Historical-FellTypeItalic}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 
\begin{luacode}
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
function ligsub ( s )
  local x = s:gsub('(\\?)([%a%@]+)', 
        function(back,text)
            if back~="" then 
               return back .. text  
            end
            text = text:gsub ( 'ffi', uchar(8776)) 
            text = text:gsub ( 'ffl', uchar(8730))
            text = text:gsub ( 'ff',  uchar(937))
            text = text:gsub ( 'fi',  uchar(64257))
            text = text:gsub ( 'fl',  uchar(64258))
            text = text:gsub ( 'as',  uchar(8721))
            text = text:gsub ( 'is',  uchar(916))
            text = text:gsub ( 'us',  uchar(247))
            text = text:gsub ( 'ct',  uchar(177))
            text = text:gsub ( 'st',  uchar(9674))
            return text
       end)
  print("x", x)
  return x
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{% 
    \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (         
              "process_input_buffer", ligsub, "ligsub" )}}

\newcommand\off{off}  % dummy macro (see below)

\begin{document}
off fit fly office baffle

as is us act step

\off --note: no ff-ligature
\end{document}
```

Remark: The only downside I can see to taking this approach is that it's definitely going to mess up the work of a screen-reader: eight of the ten ligatures -- those for `ff`, `ffi` and `fl`, `as`, `is`, `us`, `ct`, and `st` -- get rendered as `Ω`, `≈`, `√`, `Σ`, `Δ`, `±`, and `◊`, respectively. Argghh. (In contrast, `fi` and `fl` do get rendered correctly; probably not coincidentally, those are the two ligatures that have a "normal" name in the feature file, which was shown earlier.) That's not really the fault of the LuaLaTeX-based approach, though; rather, the font's messed-up name tables are to blame. Ideally, the authors and/or maintainers of the font would re-release it, this time with the name table cleaned up drastically.

Comment: Unfortunately, anyone using a screen reader or searching or copying will get unintelligible results; the feature file affects only the appearance of the text.  Better to use Igino Marini’s fonts than to spend time repairing this version, though note that even Marini’s fonts could use some fixing (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203153/7883).

Comment: @Thérèse - I'm afraid I have no experience with screen readers. However, searching for, say, "ffi" or "ffl" in the pdf file seems to pose no problem at all. Likewise, copying the ligatures from the pdf file into a plain-text file also doesn't seem to generate any untoward surprises.

Comment: Hmmm.  I wonder if there’s something going on that varies by operating system.  I just tried your example (I had been loath to install that badly made font on my system), but I get no ligatures at all.  GNU/Linux, with a vanilla TeX Live 2015, updated a few hours ago.  I’ve fixed other fonts with feature files, but this one won’t cooperate.

Comment: @Thérèse - Interesting. FWIW, I have a MacBook Pro running MacOSX 10.10.5 and MacTeX2015.

Comment: Your second approach is interesting and works on my system — not for accurate searching and extraction of text, but at least for display of the ligatures. It’s curious that the usual approach didn’t work (has anyone tried it on Windows?): according to `otfinfo`, the font is a 1994 production of the Hoefler Type Foundry, apparently an early incarnation of Historical Allsorts (http://www.typography.com/fonts/historical-allsorts/overview/).  Maybe it’s one of Apple’s versions of Hoefler fonts?

Comment: @Thérèse - Thanks for these observations. Glad to hear that the second method works on somebody else's system as well. Given that the font is not an Apple system font (at least not with MacOSX 10.10) and that's it's available free of charge from `fontpalace.com`, I doubt that Apple had any role in its production. It sure would be nice if the authors or maintainers of the font made an effort to correct the multitude of mistakes in the font's glyph naming system.

Comment: Anyone know a matching math font to use?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that your font is [freely available](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Historical-FellTypeItalic/). As I suspected, the font doesn't have OpenType features (screen capture from FontForge):

[image]

What's worse, the font is not a Unicode font. It has replaced various code points with ligatures. If you want to, you can access the ligatures by typing the characters that occupy those slots according to the Unicode standards:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Historical-FellTypeItalic}
\begin{document}
O≈ce ◊ar
\end{document}
```

Or define more sensible shortcuts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Historical-FellTypeItalic}
\newcommand{\ffi}{≈}
\newcommand{\st}{◊}
\begin{document}
O\ffi ce \st ar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there seems to be an opentype implementation of the fell types, downloadable from a link at http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/ ; the missing information about ligatures might be available with those fonts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton And of course there's no `fj` ligaure .. `:(`

Comment: no `fj` ligature -- true.  but i think in the 17th century, the british weren't writing much about fjords.  (a pity!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The thing is, revivals of old fonts from Western Europe tend to "modern" them up by including various characters used in the modern Scandinavian and Slavic languages, but they very rarely think of our ligatures ...

Comment: I tried the the font downloadable from iginomarini.com and it works well.  Thanks!

Comment: the problem, as i see it, is that the other "f" ligatures are present in unicode (although it's because they were grandfathered in, rather than because the unicode technical committee thought they really deserved it on their own), so most font "modifiers" probably don't even think about adding an `fj`.  maybe some pressure could be applied there ... i'll ask my contacts.