# LuaLaTeX: How to use a \char directive inside a string.gsub function?

Tags: luatex, strings

Consider the following MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 
\begin{luacode}
function dosub ( s )
   s =  string.gsub ( s , 'ff', '\\char64256{}') 
   return ( s )
end
--luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
off \directlua{ tex.sprint ( dosub ( \luastring{off} ) ) } off
\end{document}
```

The heart of the code is the function `dosub`, which employs the Lua function `string.gsub`. It is set to replace instances of `ff` with the glyph that contains the `ff` *ligature*. (You'll have to trust me that, for the font at hand, the ff-ligature glyph is located in "slot" 64256.) Note that, *for now*, the instruction `luatexbase.add_to_callback` instruction is commented out. (A `--` (double dash) string initiates a Lua comment.)

When this MWE is run, one gets:

[image]

Observe that the middle word, which is generated via a `\directlua` call to `dosub`, correctly contains the `ff`-ligature, whereas the first and third words do not (once again correctly, since automatic ligature generation is disabled).

The trouble starts when I uncomment the instruction

```
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" )
```

Upon recompiling, the following, fairly incomprehensible, error message results:

> (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
>
> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
>
> \scratchcounter=\count290
>
> \scratchdimen=\dimen261
>
> \scratchbox=\box256
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \let
>
> l.275   \let
>
> \pdflastform=\pdflastxform
>
> ?

I suspect this is somewhat related to the presence of a TeX macro -- `\char` -- in the replacement string part of the `string.gsub` function. To wit, if I replace `'\\char64256{}'` with `gg` (i.e., a constant string), no error message is generated (and the three instances of "ff" in the body of the document are automatically replaced with "gg").

Do I need to "wrap" or "protect" the TeX macro in some special way in order to enable the successful use of "luatexbase.add_to_callback"? Is there something else I should do? About my computing setup: I'm running MacTeX2015 (with all available updates thru this  morning applied) on a MacBookPro running MacOSX 10.10.5 "Yosemite".

Comment: `\char` isn't a macro it's a non expandable command related to typesetting, it does not generate character tokens (what you are calling strings) you could use `\uchar`

Comment: I wonder if a better approach for you problem is a feature file, as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142605/fixing-fonts-with-luatex-feature-files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for pointing out that `\char` is non-expandable. I'll definitely make use of either `\uchar` or of Michal's suggestion, which is to use the LuaTeX function `unicode.utf8.char`.

Comment: @JavierBezos - Many thanks for this suggestion. My query actually arose from difficulties experienced getting around some puzzling limitations of the Adobe Feature File approach. In my answer to the recent posting, [Historic font and missing ligatures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262009/5001), I tried the Feature File approach to activate ligature substitution. Unfortunately, for some reason, fewer than half the available ligatures got activated using this approach. That's why I've been trying to find a direct, LuaLaTeX-based, approach, to get activate all of the renegade font's ligatures.

Comment: @Mico Well, another suggestion - what about modifying directly the font table? It's a lot easier with a tex font than with an otf, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is function `unicode.utf8.char` for direct unicode character inserting in Lua functions:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 
\begin{luacode}
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
function dosub ( s )
   s =  string.gsub ( s , 'ff', uchar(64256)) 
   return ( s )
end
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
      \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" )}%
    }

\begin{document}
off \directlua{ tex.sprint ( dosub ( \luastring{off} ) ) } off
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the main issue in your code is that the callback is inserted too early and it probably replaces `ff` chars in some macros loaded in `\AtBeginDocument`. So other solution is to insert the callback in `\AtBeginDocument` as well, which reduces the risk of such collision (you should do that even in the first method):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 
\begin{luacode}
function dosub ( s )
   s =  string.gsub ( s , 'ff', '\\char64256{}') 
   return ( s )
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" )}%
}


\begin{document}
off \directlua{ tex.sprint ( dosub ( \luastring{off} ) ) } off
\end{document}
```

Edit:

There is also another catch, what if your document body include some macro with `ff` in a name? To fix that, we can use such function:

```
\begin{luacode}
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char

function dosub ( s )
  local x = s:gsub('(\\?)([%a%@]+)', function(back,text)
     if back~="" then 
        return back .. text  
     end
     return  text:gsub ( 'ff', uchar(64256)) 
  end)
  print("x", x)
  return x
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" )
\end{luacode}
```

with `s:gsub('(\\?)([%a%@]+)', function(back,text)` we catch all words, including macros. If variable `back` is not empty string, the current word is a macro and we need to return it unprocessed. Otherwise, we can apply `ff` replacing regexp.

Note that in this case `add_to_callback` is used without `AtBeginDocument`, because when `\offer` macro is defined in the preamble, it's text wouldn't be replaced. Because we now skip macros, it shouldn't matter.

And as closing remarks I would add that node processing callbacks are much better for this kind of hacks, exactly because of these problems with macros.

For instance the following code:

```lua
local uchar = unicode.utf8.char
local fchar = string.byte("f")
local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
local glue_id = node.id("glue")


local function next_status(n, node_table)
  local node_table = node_table or {}
  table.insert(node_table, n)
  if not n then return false end
  if n.id == glyph_id and n.char == fchar then
    return true, node_table
  elseif n.id == glyph_id or n.id == glue_id then 
    return false
  else
    return next_status(n.next, node_table)
  end
end


local function node_dosub(nodes)
  for n in node.traverse(nodes) do
    if n.id == glyph_id and n.char == fchar then
      local next, node_table = next_status(n.next)
      if next == true then
        n.char =  64256
        for _, x in ipairs(node_table) do
          node.remove(nodes, x)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return nodes
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "pre_linebreak_filter", node_dosub, "node_dosub" )
```

it is more complicated, because we can't operate on string level, but on individual nodes. lot of node types exists, `glyph` nodes with `node.id` 37 are important for us. every glyph node has `char` field, holding the character code. When glyph with `f` character is found, we peek next nodes to find whether there is another `f` glyph next to this one. when it is found, we replace current character with code for `ff` ligature and delete next `f` glyph.

Comment: Your point that using the `dosub` function may be operating too early if it's assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback is very well taken. To wit, if there's a macro named `\offer` in the document, nothing good is bound to happen once the `ff` character pair is replaced with the ff-ligature. Can you give a suggestion as to how `dosub` would have to be modified to make it work with, say, the `pre_linebreak_filter" callback?

Comment: @Mico I've added two more examples. One for ignoring macros with `process_input_buffer`, the second using node callback

Comment: Many thanks for these two additional solutions! I will award a "bounty" as soon as I can (within another 24 to 48 hours, I believe).

Comment: Please don't hardcode the value of the node type id for glyphs; even for a one-off example there is no good reason not to use `node.id('glyph')` (possibly via a local variable, of course).  Using the numeric value just makes the code harder to understand and potentially non-portable.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer you are right, I've edited the code

Comment: Thanks again for your additional answers. I've made good use of the `process_input_buffer`-based method in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262025/5001) to the query [Historic font and missing ligatures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262009/5001). Feel free to add a new answer to that posting to demonstrate an implementation of the `pre_linebreak_filter`-based method you've provided here.