# Difficulty accessing OpenType ligatures with LuaLaTex and fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, opentype

I’ve been trying to use Greek ligatures with the font Alfios in the version available [here](https://www.fontsaddict.com/search?searchq=alfios). In particular, I’m trying to get the o-u ligature as can be seen in the image — that I get from MS Word.

[image]

However, when I put in the code below, I get the following image as output.

[image]

Why does this not work? Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\newfontfamily{\sobergreek}{Alfios}

\begin{document}

\sobergreek\addfontfeatures{Ligatures={Rare,Historic}}
\noindent
Οὔ σε φιλῶ, Σαβίδι’, οὐχ οἷός τ’ ὤν τοῦ χάριν εἰπεῖν.\\
Οὐδὲ λέγειν δύναμαι πλείονά γ’· οὔ σε φιλῶ

\end{document}
```

---

The solution in [Historic font and missing ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262009/historic-font-and-missing-ligatures) appears related, but that’s a hack where you redefine the ligatures. I’m just trying to use the relevant font feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should activate the greek script:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\sobergreek}{Alfios}

\begin{document}

\sobergreek\addfontfeatures{Script=Greek,Ligatures={Historic}}
\noindent
Οὔ σε φιλῶ, Σαβίδι’, οὐχ οἷός τ’ ὤν τοῦ χάριν εἰπεῖν.\\
Οὐδὲ λέγειν δύναμαι πλείονά γ’· οὔ σε φιλῶ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That’s solved it. Just a clarification about the syntax: how does the script marker work? Does it activate ligatures just for Greek text, or does it say that everything following will be in Greek?