# Automatically substitute missing glyph with another in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode

For some reason the russian letter `ё` is missing in some fonts, which leads to

```
warning  (file c:/Users/mishk/OneDrive/Stuff/fonts/PTSerifPro-Regular.otf) (cff
): 'seac' character deprecated in type 2 charstring
! error:  (file c:/Users/mishk/OneDrive/Stuff/fonts/PTSerifPro-Regular.otf) (cf
f): Type2 Charstring Parser: parsing charstring failed: (status=-1, stack=5)
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However it is pretty always acceptable to substitute it with  the letter `е`, but this code doesn't work:

```
\newunicodechar{ё}{\iffontchar\font`ё ё\else{е}\fi}
\newunicodechar{Ё}{\iffontchar\font`Ё Ё\else{Е}\fi}
```

Can I do the automatic substitution **without** declaring `ё` to be an active character?

Full LuaLaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainlanguage{russian}

\newcommand{\MyPath}{C:/Users/mishk/OneDrive/Stuff/fonts/}


\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{PTSerifPro}[
    Path            =   \MyPath,
    Extension       =   .otf,
    UprightFont     =   *-Regular,
]

\newunicodechar{ё}{\iffontchar\font`ё ё\else{е}\fi}
\newunicodechar{Ё}{\iffontchar\font`Ё Ё\else{Е}\fi}

\begin{document}

    ааа еее ёёё

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's quite curious that PTSerif Pro has problem that PTSerif hasn't.

Comment: @egreg checking out https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pt-serif shows no letter `ё` also

Comment: On my machine I get it

Comment: For those complaints about “seac,” see the solution proposed at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203153

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LuaTeX you can define your own substitution rule as a font feature, see [How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154/10995)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "ediaeresis",
    type = "substitution",
    prepend = true,
    data = {
        ["ё"] = "e",
        ["Ё"] = "Е",
    }
}
}

\setmainfont{PT Serif}[RawFeature=+ediaeresis]

\begin{document}

ё Ё

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is an amazing feature!

Comment: I tried using this technique to hunt down the source of a mysterious occurrence of `^D` (`U+0004`) in a document, but it appears not to work for characters in that range. I used `luacode*` from the luacode package and added `["\x04"] = "X"`  to the data array, to no avail. So this is all very mysterious. Is this feature documented anywhere? I feel uncomfortable doing cargo cult programming.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It's documented in [“Fonts out of ConTeXt”](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I might not have found that in a million years.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Its possible to add `\fontspec` here. Like *["Ё"] = "Е",* change to *["Ё"] = "\\fontspec{Free Serif}{Е}",*?

Comment: @Balaji No, you'll need [combo fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=combofont) for that.