# How to check if a font exists in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, programming

Is there a way to check if a font exists in XeLaTeX? I am aware of [Check for missing fonts/characters in XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/check-for-missing-fonts-characters-in-xelatex), but sadly the one answer only refers to the log. I am interested for a test via code.

Background:

I am trying to define a command that checks a series of fonts and uses the first one that it finds (similar to the CSS properties)

```
 p{font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;}
```

I intend to use pgf keys and here is a MWE example.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{ifxetex}
 % Generic defaults
 \ifxetex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
   \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
   \setsansfont{Minion Pro}
\else
   \usepackage{mathpazo}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% keys
\pgfkeys{/fonts/.is family}
\def\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/fonts}} 
\cxset{%
  serif/.code=\rmfamily,
  Serif/.code=\rmfamily,
  font-name/.store in =\fontname@cx,
}
\cxset{
   serif,
   font-name=Times New Roman,
}

\ifxetex
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
  % code to be added here for iterating through list etc..
  \setmainfont{\fontname@cx}
  \setsansfont{Minion Pro}
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Ultimately the key

```
font-family={Times New Roman, Some Other Font, Another Font, serif}
```

should iterate via all the font names. if none is found the serif value will trigger the default `\rmfamily`. I can code the iteration etc, but I am stuck on the test.

Comment: The problem here is that TeX is about exacting output, hence the fact that you don't get 'auto-substitution' of missing glyphs, etc. So I'm not sure this is that easy/doable.

Comment: Check my answer on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/check-for-missing-fonts-characters-in-xelatex

Comment: @JosephWright Won't you please have a look at the answers below and give us some comments, or even mangle an answer:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help (take from [XeTeX mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-August/017833.html)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \def\myfont{"Persian Modern"}% first preferred font
  \def\myfallback{"XB Zar"} % if first font not avaliable
  \count255=\interactionmode
  \batchmode
  \font\bodyfont=\myfont\space at 10pt
  \ifx\bodyfont\nullfont
    \font\bodyfont = \myfallback\space at 10pt
    \ifx\bodyfont\nullfont
      \errorstopmode
      \errmessage{no suitable font found}
    \else
      \let\myfont=\myfallback
    \fi
  \fi
  \interactionmode=\count255
  \bodyfont
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it certainly does. The way I read it uses batchmode to silence the errors and then does the substitution. I can turn this into a list no issue. I will wait a bit to accept the answer.

Comment: The link to the discussion is very good. I might even be able to suppress the errors via `\suprressfontnotfounderror`, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Simurgh's [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/check-for-missing-fonts-characters-in-xelatex) here is a first attempt to check for a number of fonts. I run through the full loop for convenience, although one would need to break at the first font found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\alist{Times New Roman,Tahoma,test}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
 \count255=\interactionmode
  \batchmode
\@for\next:=\alist\do{%
    \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname\next\endcsname{\next}
    \setbox0=\hbox{\csname\next\endcsname A}
    \ifdim\ht0=0pt \next\ does not exist\\ \else \next\ does exist\\\fi
 }
\interactionmode=\count255
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

As normal XeLaTeX can go into a few seconds of silence, looking for fonts, so be a bit patient if you run the MWE.

Comment: Please see my `Edit2` answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/check-for-missing-fonts-characters-in-xelatex/53451#53451

Comment: @Simurgh12 Thanks your second answer is a better way to also check if a font exists. If a font does not exist -> silence errors and check for A. It fails the test, certainly as used above.

Comment: No, test for A was an example. You actually should check a range of characters (depending on your application).