# XeLaTeX: Set an alternative font in case it is not found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am setting up the packages for a shared project with someone who's not familiar with LaTeX. I want to use some of our local fonts. I used XeLaTeX and it works. However, we'll also use a notebook where these fonts might not be available.

As I intend to minimise the need of modification on the packages loaded, I would like to know whether there is a way to specify alternatives fonts to XeLaTeX in case it doesn't find the first one (as it is done in HTML/CSS for example).

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}
This should be in \textit{Adobe Garamond Pro} if available.
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53448/17423 may be a starting point, but I would hope that a nicer interface has popped up in the past two years :)

Comment: @Sean Thanks, I'll try it. Sure, I was hoping for something like \setmainfont{Garamond, Times} ...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like see as well. XeTeX is in active enough development that this type of interface might be feasible now; I don't know.

Comment: @SeanAllred It would end any pretence that compiling the same document on different systems will give identical output. But I guess this is gone for XeTeX/LuaTeX, at least, anyway.

Comment: @cfr Archivability is *very* important, but introducing that `,` is the user's choice.

Comment: @SeanAllred True. I'm not necessarily against the idea. It just seems to me that while it seems great to be able to use any font, on the other hand, that very advantage is also a disadvantage. (I sometimes think people are over enthusiastic about the changes. Not that there are not many benefits, of course. But there is a definite cost to those benefits. Or several, actually. This is one of them.)

Comment: Why not copy the tex files along with the font files? You can get XeTeX load fonts from the working directory, even if not installed on the system.

Comment: @cfr If only it would.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer If only what would what?

Comment: @cfr If only it would end the pretence that TeX  documents are  unconditionally portable (in reply to your first comment).  I have never seen it to be true for users who really needed it, and for others who didn't it has made them unnecessarily picky (refusing to make a trivial change on 3 lines of a 15-year old document - I have seen it).  I think we've reached a point where this claim is actually harmful.  A more useful and accurate claim is that TeX documents will still be usable after decades, and under carefully controlled conditions can be made to produce the same output.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer Up to a point. But this would result in very different output on systems with identical installations of TeX, for example. But, as I say, that can happen anyway once you are using Xe/LuaTeX and system fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in both xelatex and lualatex and sets the document in Pagella for me:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\onlywarniffontnotfound}{}
 {
  \suppressfontnotfounderror = \c_one 
  %\font_suppress_not_found_error:
  \msg_redirect_name:nnn {fontspec}{font-not-found}{warning}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\onlywarniffontnotfound
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\expandafter\ifx\the\font\nullfont
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \expandafter\ifx\the\font\nullfont
    \typeout{hmm your document might be a bit white, sorry}
  \else
    \typeout{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \fi
\else
\typeout{you have Adobe Garamond Pro}
\fi



\begin{document}
\showoutput
This should be in \textit{Adobe Garamond Pro} if available.
\end{document}
```

(`\onlywarniffontnotfound` supplied by @egreg)

Comment: Instead of `\scrollmode` you could set `\suppressfontnotfounderror=1`

Comment: @egreg ooh very modern:-)

Comment: @egreg I just tried it and fontspec still stops

Comment: This doesn't compile for me in either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I don't have Adobe Garamond Pro, so I get a font-not-found `fontspec` error regardless of whether I use `\scrollmode` or `\suppressfontnotfounderror=1`.

Comment: @JasonZentz that's very odd, I don't have Garamond Pro either and it picks up pagella for me, which tex distribution do you have? It echoes the font not found error for Garamod pro to the terminal but should move on and try Pagella without stopping.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `fontspec` uses `\suppressfontnotfounderror=1` somewhere, but then it defines some function to raise an error independently of this.

Comment: Well, I guess it does create a PDF with Pagella, but TeXStudio complains about the font-not-found error, says "exited with errors," and doesn't display the PDF automatically as it normally would.

Comment: I have TeX Live 2015, with all packages updated yesterday.

Comment: It does work for me if I use the terminal to compile, but TeXStudio (my normal editor) doesn't like it.

Comment: @JasonZentz you could try the modified code above, no idea what texshop will do with it but it avoids a primitive tex error. so doesn't need \scrollmode

Comment: Yes, the modified version works fine in TeXStudio.

Comment: Very nice ! To keep a clean preamble I could put your answer inside a command (with 3 or 4 arguments for the substitutable fonts and add a default font) without problem and that makes it exactly what I looked for, i.e. a command like `\listofsubstitutablefonts{Adobe Garamond Pro}{Georgia}{Helvetica}`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on XeLaTeX from the terminal. `Undefined control sequence. [\onlywarniffontnotfound]`.

Comment: @Matthew oh something changed in expl3 or fontspec, I'll update the answer in a bit

Comment: @Matthew try now, I reverted to primitive syntax for one setting

Comment: change is fontspec, here https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/commit/b608b00ac57e0282da9d65b4647a42e0211ee202#diff-279d504a58ccd623471a80e1d7a3f693