# Choosing font depending on the OS (Win, Linux)

Tags: fonts, xetex

How can I do the macro which will automatilcally choose font if compiles on Win (TNR font) or on Linux (Liberation for example). Using XeTex (TeXLive).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} %want to choose Liberation on Linux, TNR in Win
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic, Scale=0.8]{Ubuntu-Light}
```

Comment: There seems to be a package [ifplatform](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ifplatform). I have not tried it but this is the first result I found on CTAN.

Comment: Maybe you can "simply" put one of the fonts as fall back if the other does not exist, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53448/36296

Comment: @Artemis great! very powerful macro, thank you for the answer

Comment: @samcarter thank you, sometimes the best way is simplest way .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already stated in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348985/choosing-font-depending-on-the-os-win-linux?noredirect=1#comment856885_348985) there is a package called [**ifplatform**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifplatform) which can solve this problem. It should work also for LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX, not just XeTeX.

**Attention:** Keep the warning from the documentation in mind, that all macros except `\ifwindows` do not work as expected unless `--shell-escape` is enabled.

For your example the solution would be best written as:

```
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\ifwindows
% Load Windows font here
\else
% Load Non-Windows font here
\fi
```

Comment: Thank you! Because of my limited experience, I would have understood this much longer.