# What font can I use to compile my document on both Linux and Windows?

Tags: fonts, windows, linux

What font can I use so that I can compile my document on both Linux and Windows?
I have been using Calibri but now that I'm on my Linux machine I have to change it. I have to switch between Linux and Windows.

Comment: Every font which is part of TeXlive. (IIRC MikTeX is more permissive with licences.) You might want to give a look at [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59403/82917)

Comment: If you have a valid license for Calibri (sic!), it should be possible to install it on Linux as well. That said, there is a free clone by the name of Carlito which, for all intents and purposes, is almost the same. It is metric-compatible, at the very least: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/carlito

Comment: @Ingmar it is metric compatible, correct, but the difference between Calibri and Carlito is easily spotable, imho, when one knows one of the two fonts. Also, the spelling of Calibri is correct, so why the "(sic!)"?

Comment: I edited the question to correct the name... That said, some other free or licensed font on both Windows and Linux shouldn't be much of an an issue.

Comment: As an alternative solution you could automatically choose a different font depending on the OS and/or depending on the availability of the font, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348985/choosing-font-depending-on-the-os-win-linux and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201521/xelatex-set-an-alternative-font-in-case-it-is-not-found.